# Creating map with multiple selectable layers using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, arcgis-online

I want to make a map with an option for the user to choose between 3 layers to view. All layers with a certain type of point. If possible, I would also like the user to view more than one layer at a time if they select it.

Is this possible within ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible using the ArcGIS for JavaScript API. First, you have to create a [`Map`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html) with three layers. If these are your layers, you'll want to store them as FeatureLayers using ArcGIS Online. Then, you can add the [`LayerList`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList.html) widget to your map. [Here is an example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-layerlist/index.html) of the widget's functionality.